# Show ActivityIndicator in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a function to fetch items from an API that is inside `UseEffect`. And i'm looking to call this function every time the `status` of the `selectedItem` or the `items` changes and show an `ActivityIndicator` before the function returns the result. The `ActivityIndicator` appears when  the items are uploading but not when the `status` of the `selectedItem` changes ?

I have my code like this :

```js
export default () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const getItems = () => {
    get('/api/items').then((rep) => {
        setItems(rep);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, [selectedItem.status]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <View style={[styles.spinnerContainer, styles.horizontal]}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      ) : ((items !== [])
        && (
          <SectionList
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
            style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, }}
            sections={items}
            refreshing={isLoading}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            ...
          />
        ))}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setLoading(true) inside getItems

```
     const getItems = () => {
       setLoading(true);
       get('/api/items').then((rep) => {
          setItems(rep);
          setLoading(false);
       });
     };
```